concatenar en excel campos que comiencen con las primeras 2 letras
Tengo 2 hojas de mi libro de excel, donde c/u tiene su columna código
en Hoja1 tengo:



código




01


02


03



Y en la hoja2 tengo lo siguiente:



código




0101


0102


0201


0202


0301



Mi resultado deseado es que en hoja3 me muestre concatenado todos los valores que se relacionen con la hoja1 :



concatenados




01-0101


01-0102


02-0201


02-0202


03-0301



he intentado esta formula:
=SI(IZQUIERDA(Hoja2!A2,2)=IZQUIERDA(A2,2),CONCATENAR(A2,"-",Hoja2!A2),"")
Pero solo me trae la primera fila correcta, la siguiente no, porque ya no busca los demas valores que tengan 01 al inicio de la hoja2:
|01-0101|

Ayúdame a comprender algo... ¿Necesitas que en cada celda de la Hoja3, se concatenen los dos primeros números de la Hoja2 y luego el valor de la celda? o en su lugar, lo que buscas es que en la celda A2 de la Hoja3 se agrupen todos los códigos que inicien con 01, en la celda A3 todos los que inicien en 02 y en la celda A4 todos los que inicien en 03?

@DjCrazy seria la primera opción que se concatenen los de la hoja 1, que empaten en la hoja 2 sus 2 caracteres

No tengo claro en qué influyen los códigos de la hoja uno, pero viendo tu output, por lo que se ve tú quieres siempre que los dos primeros dígitos se añadan por la izquierda seguidos de un guión:

La fórmula para concatenar es: =IZQUIERDA(A2;2)&"-"&A2
Si puedes explicar por qué se necesita la Hoja1 lo modifico, pero el resultado que pides se puede conseguir usando únicamente lo que tienes en la Hoja2
